# Should all functions in a service be in the return-object?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning Angular and have no previous experience with object-oriented programming.

When I'm writing services, sometimes i'm wrinting functions that I don't think will be used outside of the service. Should I write them like normal functions:

```
function someting(){
...
}
```

or should I put them in the return-object.

```
return{
   something: function(){
     ...
}
```

What are the pros and cons? Does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the return object should contain the public interface for your service (i.e. the public methods). Thus, if you create functions that do not require to be accessed from outside, they do not need to be part of the returned object.

Best.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is entirely accurate: it sounds like this answer is valid for an Angular "factory", and not a "service". I was under the impression that the return value for a "service" isn't used.

Comment: @MichalCharemza I think you are wrong in this regard.

Comment: The service factory indeed returns an object. From Angular documentation: "Creating Services
Application developers are free to define their own services by registering the service's name and service factory function, with an Angular module.

The service factory function generates the single object or function that represents the service to the rest of the application. The object or function returned by the service is injected into any component (controller, service, filter or directive) that specifies a dependency on the service."

Comment: @KristofferNolgren You're right actually: I didn't know that the return value of a constructor (which is what the "service" function definition is) can be used. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new "Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process"